# How to include directories in cmake generated visual studio projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, configuration, cmake, include

I have (roughly) the following CMakeLists.txt

```
project(Test)

set(SOURCE
123.cpp
456.cpp )

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
unit_test_framework REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

message("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

add_executable(Tests ${SOURCE})
```

The message generated by

```
message("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

is

```
C:\boost_1_40_0
```

When I generate the visual studio 2008 project files, all is fine... except that the in the project's properties, there is nothing in the "Additional Include Directories" in the C/C++ section. When I build, I get

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/test/unit_test.hpp': No such file or directory
```

However, the file is right there, under C:\boost_1_40_0. Is there something more to do?

For now I'm putting boost in the global c++ directories, but I was wondering if there was a reason for this ?

Thank you!

Comment: ok... the include_directories and link_directories need to be after the add_executable...

Comment: If you've found the answer, you can answer your own question (and accept the answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok... the include_directories and link_directories need to be after the add_executable...